# replacing a section of a website with Xmlhttprequest

Tags: xmlhttprequest

I have managed to make xhr work on a website with normal text documents (I can update the innerHtml of a div with a text grabbed from a document), what I'm struggling with is to do the same with sections of the page - replacing certain divs with new ones from an external html file. The external file contains only the divs to replace:

```
    <img class="logos svg animate-me" src="img/mga_light.svg"/>
    <p class="animate-me"> 120 <br> Bonus</p>
    <a class="fade" href="http://www.google.com">
    <button class="animate-me" style="max-width:90vw;">PLAY</button></a>
```

My code is the following:

```
function loadTop(event) {
    

    
    let sider = document.querySelectorAll(".country"); 
    for (let i = 0; i < sider.length; i++) { 
        
    var topcasinos = event.target.getAttribute('data-top');   

        
    setTimeout(function() {  
        
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) { 
        
    

        document.getElementById("topthree").innerHTML = this.responseXML; }
  }; xhttp.open("POST", topcasinos, true); xhttp.responseType = "document"; xhttp.send(); 
        

        }, 500);
    } 
}
```

This function replaces the divs with "[object HTMLDocument]" when executed, and I don't know how to change this into actual divs that would simply update the content of the website with the new divs replacing the old divs.

"topthree" is the wrapper of the divs to replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to convert the [object HTMLDocument] to actual html raw text:

```
document.getElementById("topthree").innerHTML = 
new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(this.responseXML);
```

note:
later I found out, its not really working well together with intersection observer, the original divs (which were also copied to external document, just changed with different content) had classes that hide and show the divs when entering the viewport or leaving it - this is not really working with content that has been replaced by xmlhttprequest, they are stuck in a hidden state - so probably best to remove intersection observer specific classes from divs that are in the external document to be inserted in the html.